# Probability problem regarding 3rd and 4th pick

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say, there are $3$ bags and there are $6,5 \text{ and }4$ balls in those bags respectively. Now if $4$ balls were taken randomly without replacement, What is the probability that 3rd and 4th balls are taken from the same bag?

**My Try:**
$$=\dfrac{15}{15}\times\dfrac{14}{14}\times\dfrac{13}{13}\times(\dfrac{3}{12}+\dfrac{2}{12}+\dfrac{1}{12})=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Is there any problem ?

Comment: Do you choose randomly a ball or first a bag and then a ball in the bag?

Comment: obviously ball.

Comment: This means that this is equivalent to the problem of one bag with 15 balls of three colors, does not it?

Comment: yes. Two scenarios are analogous.

Comment: I can't follow your computation at all and the answer seems far too high.  To solve the problem:  What's the probability that both are from the first bag?  Second bag?  Third bag?  Then just add.

Comment: How is it "obvious" that you choose a ball randomly instead of a bag?  The latter is far more natural, the former is hard to implement.  In any case, you should edit your post to explain what you meant.

Comment: There is no condition needed for choosing any bag until you take your 4th ball. Because for the first 3 balls you can choose any ball from any bag. So the probability is 1 each time for those first 3 cases. I guess.

Comment: Your guess is uncorrect or at least counterintuitive. If your replace bags with colors the problem will be unambiguous.

Comment: why? Say for your coloured balls, it doesn't have to be obvious to choose any colour first for choosing the first 3 balls. You can pick any ball from any colour. So, for those probabilities are 1. Only 4th ball will be dependent upon the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your solution is that it cannot be followed. You should explain how did you come to this expression. In any case the result is not correct as the following simple calculation shows.

As clarified in the comment the problem is equivalent to that of drawing of balls of three colors from a bag, which can be solved as follows.

There are altogether:
$$
N=15\cdot14
$$
ways to fill the third and fourth positons.

Fixing the color of the balls on these positions one obtains the following numbers of corresponding combinations:
$$
N_1=6\cdot5,\quad N_2=5\cdot4,\quad N_3=4\cdot3,
$$
so that the probability in question is:
$$
\frac{N_1+N_2+N_3}{N}=\frac{31}{105}.
$$

Comment: Why N=15*14? you have already taken 2 balls if you are considering 3rd and 4th ball.
So, N=13*12
Then how N1=6*5? what if you have already taken one or two from the same colour in your first and second pick? it also goes for N2 and N3.

Comment: Every of 15 balls can be on the third position complemented by every of 14 remaining balls on the 4th position.

Comment: Why? we are picking "without replacement".

Comment: If we were picking "with replacement" the answer would be different.

Comment: You hadn't explained your point yet.

Comment: My point is that the answer is independent of the positions. They can be 3+4 or 1+2 or 1+4. Actually it is independent of the number of drawn balls as well. It suffice that there are at least two draws.

Comment: For intuitive understanding it is useful to imagine that all balls are numbered and to note that all possible $15\cdot14\cdot13\cdot12$ ordered sequences of balls are equiprobable. Therefore it is sufficient to count the sequences which we are interested in.